# Gridview Custom controls and javascript functions c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, custom-controls

I have a custom control which is basically a Gridview and its first column is a TemplateField with a checkbox in the header and a checkbox for each of the rows. Clicking on the header checkbox should call some javascript to toggle each of the checkboxes in every row on display... it's a common requirement as we know.

My problem is (I'll go into more detail later) that when I have 2 of these controls on the same page, and I click the checkbox that selects all the chkboxes, the page calls the wrong bit of javascript (which only appears once on the rendered html page) and checks all the checkboxes on the wrong grid !

Here's my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkSelectAll" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this)"/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelected"></asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
        $('#<%=gridPublishers.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () 
            {
                if (this != chk) { this.checked = chk.checked; }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

So, the parent page has 2 of these controls on it. The first grid shows All the publishers and the other shows the publishers that have been selected from the first...

```
<h2>Selected Publishers</h2>
<cac:GridPublishers id="GridSelectedPublishers" runat="server" CssClass="GridSelectedPublishers" BindSource="DynamicFromSession" ShowMultiSelectCol="true" ShowFilterControls="false" NoRecordsMessage="No Publishers have been selected yet." />
<br /><br />
<h2>All Publishers</h2>
<cac:GridPublishers id="GridPublishers" runat="server" ShowMultiSelectCol="true" CssClass="GridPublishers"  />
```

As I said earlier, the javascript only appears once on the rendered html page (and I understand why) but how can I get each instance of the custom control calling it's own javascript (or an alternative method) so that it only toggles its own checkboxes ??

...

I've also tried adding 2 javascript events and on grid bind trying to find the master checkbox  and assign it the correct JS function, but I've searched each cell of the header row, and col 0 (where the control should be) holds 0 controls.

...

I've also tried adding a hidden button that on page load, I can assign it the correct javascript function (that will affect the correct gridview) and then the master checkbox fires the hidden button onClientClick event, but as the page reloads, it gets confused and fires the click event twice and from both grids apparently !

Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you realise that this line of code is causing the root problem of selecting the checkboxes in the wrong datagrid:

`#<%=gridPublishers.ClientID%>').find`

It's always going to pickup gridPublishers, and not GridSelectedPublishers.

So this is the area to fix.  What you need to do is make this function a bit more abstract:

```
<input type="checkbox" ID="chkSelectAll" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this)"/>
```

The onclick event passes 'this', but that's only a reference to the checkbox which isn't much help.

I'd suggest you try and make it something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ID="chkSelectAll" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this,'GridSelectedPublishers')"/>
```

And then use the 2nd argument in the javascript function to grab the right datagrid.

Your problem now, is how to get that 2nd argument in there....you may be able to think of your own solution for this, but I would be tempted to make that checkbox an ASP checkbox, and find it during datagrid render and assign it the onClick with Attribute.Add

Making sense?

Answer (score 1):

I've already marked "ben_the_builder's" answer  as correct because it got me along the right line.

When I bind my grids I call this function:

```
private void Register_CheckAllControl_JScript()
    {
        // THIS IS A WORKAROUND FOR WHEN TWO OF THE SAME CUSTOM CONTROL LIVE ON THE SAME PAGE, EACH CONTROL'S JAVASCRIPT MUST SPECIFY THE ID OF THE CONTROL TO AFFECT

        if (gridPublishers.HeaderRow != null)
        { 
            CheckBox chkAll = gridPublishers.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelectAll") as CheckBox;

            if (chkAll != null)
            {
                if (this.BindSource == Enumerators.BindSource.DynamicFromSession)
                {
                    chkAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelectAllCheckboxes(this,'GridSelectedPublishers');");
                }
                else
                {
                    chkAll.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SelectAllCheckboxes(this,'GridPublishers');");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To access the "master" checkbox from code behind - it had to be an ASP control. an input control just wasn't recognised when iterating through the header cell collection.

My Javascript needed a little tweaking for the IDs to be correct. The control name I'm passing had to be name it was given on the parent page which belongs in the middle of the three tier final html output name (see the example, it'll make sense...)

My Javascript looks like this now:

```
<script>
        function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk, ctrlName) {
            //if ctrlName = "

            $("#MainContent_" + ctrlName + "_gridPublishers").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                if (this != chk) { this.checked = chk.checked; }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use parameters.  Instead of hard coding #<%=gridPublishers.ClientID%> into your javascript function, use the this parameter you pass to the function to determine the name of the grid view that contains the checkbox, then check everything inside that grid view.

Comment: Thanks Vulcronos, but that was my very first approach, the "this" parameter was still getting confused and would always affect the 2nd custom control loaded during the page lifecycle.

Comment: @wotney The this parameter shouldn't ever get confused.  IT should pass in the checkbox that was clicked.  If it is getting confused that is extremely weird.

Comment: @ Vulcronos - I've changed my line of javascript to :               this.find("input:checkbox").each(function () {if (this != chk) { this.checked = chk.checked; } ...  But I'm getting "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'"

Comment: The first line of the JS function is now:  alert($(this).attr('id')); but the alert returns "Undefined"

Comment: @wotney Try alert(this.attr("id"));